# Elasticsearch issue on searching nested array objects not working

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am currently using ES version 2.3.5. I have an ES mapping automatically created by a springboot REST project:

```
{
  "customer" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "customer" : {
        "properties" : {
          "addresses" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "include_in_parent" : true,
            "properties" : {
              "address1" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "address2" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "address3" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "country" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "id" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "latitude" : {
                "type" : "double"
              },
              "longitude" : {
                "type" : "double"
              },
              "postcode" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "state" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "town" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "unit" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "companyNumber" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "contactMethods" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "include_in_parent" : true,
            "properties" : {
              "type" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "description" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "value" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "contacts" : {
            "properties" : {
              "contactType" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "detail" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "id" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
          },
          "name" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "parent" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "include_in_parent" : true,
            "properties" : {
              "id" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "name" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "type" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "status" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "timeCreated" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "timeUpdated" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "type" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A search service class builds the query. For example, querying an address field by issuing "addresses.address1:Queensland" on an endpoint, the query will be:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "should" : {
      "query_string" : {
        "query" : "(addresses.address1:Queensland)",
        "fields" : [ "type", "name", "companyNumber", "status", "parent.id", "parent.name", "parent.type", "addresses.id", "addresses.unit", "addresses.address1", "addresses.address2", "addresses.address3", "addresses.town", "addresses.state", "addresses.postcode", "addresses.country", "contactMethods.type", "contactMethods.value", "contactMethods.description" ],
        "default_operator" : "or",
        "analyze_wildcard" : true,
        "lenient" : true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which returns a correct document. Example response:

```
{
    "page": 1,
    "pageSize": 10,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "totalElements": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "timeCreated": "2016-09-01T14:52:44Z",
            "timeUpdated": "2016-09-01T15:25:46Z",
            "type": "BUSINESS",
            "name": "John Doe",
            "companyNumber": "1000000002",
            "status": "PENDING",
            "addresses": [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "address1": "Queensland Street",
                    "address2": "Casa Fuego",
                    "town": "New Kingslanding",
                    "state": "QA",
                    "postcode": "2222",
                    "country": "AU",
                    "longitude": 151.080739,
                    "latitude": -33.770029
                }
            ],
            "contactMethods": [
                {
                    "type": "MOBILE",
                    "value": "0123456789"
                },
                {
                    "type": "EMAIL",
                    "value": "john@doe.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But if I query a contactMethods field by "contactMethods.type:EMAIL" or "contactMethods.type:MOBILE" or even "contactMethods.type:*" even lowercase "email" and "mobile" returns empty or 0 document(s).

What causes this?

Comment: That's because `contactMethods` is a `nested` field and nested fields [cannot be queried via a `query_string` query](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/16551) yet.

Comment: "addresses" field was queried as the example above.

Answer (score 0):

Nested properties are indexed as different documents. Need to use the nested operator. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-query.html.

Comment: You should provide an example just in case your link goes 404 at some point.

Comment: @Ricardo As the example above, addresses is also nested but it works. But on contactMethods it doesn't.